# Oil-filter chain-wrench repair: is it possible? Nissan NP200/Renault Sandero 1.6.,8v

Tags: oil, chain, wrench, filter

In attempting to remove my oil-filter, my chain-wrench has broken i.e. the chain part of it. The engine had not been warmed up before(as there is now no oil in the sump) but it was a very hot day.

The filter is so tight it just won't budge.

So I have a broken chain and a squished filter which is still screwed tightly on.

Is there a way to fix the chain, or should I just go and buy another one?

(a related question is how to get the filter off, which I'll post separately)

Comment: Most canister oil filters recommend screwing them on until it seats, then another 3/4 turn to squish the thick foam gasket. A little oil smeared on the gasket helps with sealing.